# my Dll size blown out by introducing large switch cases, how can I reduce my Dll size(MSVC C++)?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, optimization, case, switch-statement

My Dll size is of 2 MB. Now I have a situation where I need to add a switch case with 2500 case arms.. each case invoking a function. So total 2500 different functions are being called through this switch case with 2500 cases in it. (The entire code for 2500 functions is already exist in the DLL of 2MB. Extra code included is only switch cases). Now my issue is that the size of the Dll is increased by 15 MB in the Release build resulting DLL size into 17 MB which is huge as per my requirements. Please suggest me some way where i can maintain my Dll size to the minimum by handling switch cases properly.. any alternative methods..
I am using MSVC 2005, c/c++. I invoked optimization to minimize size(/01), /ltcg, (/OPT:REF), (/OPT:ICF),etc ..all best possible optimization features. (Not using precompiled headers)

Your suggestions are much needed

Thanks in Advance
Anil

Comment: What are you doing this for? Why have you chosen this design? What are you trying to accomplish? There is almost certainly a better way to do whatever it is.

Comment: I think that's pretty much what he's asking for help finding...?

Comment: @JohnB - This is true, but the answer he wants is going to be different depending on why he came up with the 2500 case switch design in the first place.

Comment: Are you sure that all the code is already in the DLL? The linker might throw it out because it's not used.

Comment: i hope the code is automatically generated ...

Comment: @Ringding - Yes the entire code is in the DLL of 2MB, i got this issue with size when i started writing switch cases to call each of those funtions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With The intial trials i came to conclusion that theres nothing much when we try with Function pointers.. i found contiguous switch cases and function pointers are almost same as per my requirement where as maps are blowing my Dll size abit more.   Here the issue is not with the switch cases as i thought but with the code that i have written in the functions that i am calling.. I have used many STLs, some common code.. and still fews things like strings.. that i am looking at which causing code bloat. It may take some time for me to make my code efficient. This Answer is to give an idea for beginners like me and a request for the experienced people to suggest some points where and how code can bloat.(Ofcourse I dont forget google)  Still I am left with many loops and gaps .. I need to find what happens when code generated by the compiler.. its very interesting to know

Answer (score 3):

If all the functions have the same signature, consider populating a `map` or similar data structure with function pointers with what you're switching on as the lookup key. No human being is going to be able to understand a switch statement with 2500 cases, so I would recommend not having one in your code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I have tried with map and function pointers on a sample of 200 functions/cases.. what i observed is my dll size is still increasing with maps but decreasing with function pointers but not significantly (only .1 MB decreased per 200 cases). Now i want to see the change when i applied to total 2500 cases. I am a bit confused whether my function ptr table will take 2500 function names as array elements. I will update once i am done with it.

Answer (score 2):

Almost certainly you have a lot of duplicated code in your case blocks (via macros / inline functions / STL). Change your case to use a **non-inline** function with arguments, to reduce each case block to merely "HandleGenericCase(x);". Don't use STL or other template/inlined code in your case blocks.

Without seeing your code, it will be hard to give a good answer in which case "verify the specific cause of bloat" is really the best advice.

Comment: Thanks Tenfour, I am looking into my code for the cause of bloat.. as I thought there should be no connection with switch cases and the size of DLL

Comment: it would help if you could paste an example of a case block, and the function signature of the functions you call in that block.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the switch statement takes 100 bytes per case, that is only 1/4 MB, and it is probably a lot less.

Can you get a map file of the dll? I would do that and just sample it at random a few times to see what kinds of functions are in there. My bet is it's full of stuff you don't really need, often generated by templates.

Also, I bet those 2500 functions contain a lot of gas. If the switch statement is the only way they are called, they could be expanded in-line right in the switch statement, saving a lot of entry/exit code.

Comment: Yes there is some common code in my functions, and as you suggested I cant expand in-line right in the switch case as the code  of those functions is in the range of 200 lines to 400 lines. I am looking through my code for the cause of bloat.. as I thought there should be no connection with switch cases and the size of DLL

Comment: @Anil: 2500 functions times 300 lines/function = 750,000 lines of code just in the functions, give or take. That's massive.

Comment: Yes thats massive, entire code length is around 900,000 lines.. working to decrease it.. may decrease to a 750,000 lines hopefully.

Comment: @Anil: I bet if you brought in a refactoring buzzard, it would gorge itself, and feed all its friends too.