# Is there any alternative way of writing the code instaed of using switch statement in c++

Tags: c++, switch-statement

We are building DLL's using C++ .As we are having 400 cases in the size of the DLL is getting bigger in size so is there any alternative way of using instead of switch

Comment: Can you also please mention, the type of action you are taking, and the values you are checking in switch.

Comment: Depends a lot on what the code does.

Comment: Could you explain more the context? Why are you doing that? You should have stopped and looked for alternatives way earlier, say, at 8 or 10 cases.

Comment: Example code would help.

Comment: I'm a little puzzled why the size of the switch is related to the size of the DLL. What does this switch do that outweighs the rest of the code in the DLL? Can you explain?

Comment: I would like to reduce the size of DLL

Comment: You'll reduce the size by quite a lot if you factor the almost-identical blocks of code in the last four `if` blocks into a separate function, and replace the crazy code to clear the map with `taxData_PA01953.clear()` - especially if all 400 functions are written similarly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends on the data type you're switching over. If it's a dense int range, use a lookup table storing function pointers. In other cases use a `std::map` from switched-over values to function pointers.

Comment: The compiler should transform a dense int range into lookup table anyway.

Comment: This is just making the code more obscure and harder to read as the implementation is already doing that internally.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the switching isn't the problem.

There's a whole lot of code duplication between your branches (I suppose you have something like 395 more) so you should be able to shrink your DLL by abstracting out the common parts; the only difference is what field you're retrieving and the calculation you perform with it.  The vast majority of your code can be shared between branches if they're all as similar as those you've posted.
If your compiler isn't doing any pooling of strings, so you have several instances of your query templates, that isn't helping either.

Factor out all your conditions, DB queries and string concatenations into functions and see where that takes you.

You should do this anyway as it will make maintenance and further expansion much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant: [my Dll size blown out by introducing large switch cases, how can I reduce my Dll size(MSVC C++)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4992412/my-dll-size-blown-out-by-introducing-large-switch-cases-how-can-i-reduce-my-dll?tab=active)

Comment: I'm not sure whether 400 if-else's will be any more readable.

Comment: Even by using thismy DLL size did not reduce

Answer (score 0):

The size of the switch case and size of the Dll should have no direct relation. The only way size can be controlled is by reducing the common code and using STLs properly besides to the defalut optimization options ur compiler gives